# How to display quote (") symbol in ant script

Tags: scripting, ant, escaping, properties, quotes

My ant script is,

```
<target name="temp">
    <property name="argument" value="xyz abc"/>
    <echo message=" & quot;${argument}& quot;"/>
</target>
```

Output is

```
xyz abc
```

Expected Output is

```
"xyz abc"
```

How to get the expected output. I tried like this `&quot;quot;${argument}&quot;quot;`, this is also not working.

Note : I am using ant 1.8.2 and `antcontrib` in windows 7.

Comment: Updated. Removed some mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a space between `&` and `quot;`?

This works for me:

```
<target name="temp">
    <property name="argument" value="xyz abc"/>
    <echo message="&quot;${argument}&quot;"/>
</target>
```

Output:

```
temp:
     [echo] "xyz abc"
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 469 milliseconds
```